# Phonegap Camera and FileTransfer Background Thread

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, cordova

I´ve been building a Phonegap Application for Android and iOS. Everything is set up and it´s starting, but if I open the Camera application throughout my Phonegap App I´m always getting this warning : 
**THREAD WARNING: ['Camera'] took '760.514893' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.**

I read something about background threads in the Phonegap Documentations, but I didn´t understand what I have to change or what to do.

Anybody got the same problems? Thanks for the responses.

Comment: It is not a problem, it's just a warning because such actions block the UI <- bad behaviour.